# Finding records in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I wanted to show that a record in one table exists in another table and used the code below. Would this be possible?

```
CASE WHEN EXISTS (
SELECT  *
FROM    tblA a
        INNER JOIN tblB b ON a.AccountID = b.AccountID
                ) THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END
```

Comment: I assume this is within one of the fields that are being selected from a larger query?  Yes it is possible, but probably better to use a join within the larger query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Dave Gugg mentioned in his comment that is possible. The alternative is using a LEFT JOIN and for those rows that are not matched in table B display NO, for those that match display YES:

```
SELECT  a.*, CASE WHEN b.AccountID IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END as YesNoCol
FROM    tblA a
LEFT JOIN tblB b ON a.AccountID = b.AccountID
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Do something like this instead:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
                  FROM tblA AS A
                  INNER JOIN tblB AS B 
                      ON A.AccountID = B.AccountID) > 1
            THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END AS T;
```